# Symfony ignore 404 status code for get request

Tags: symfony, http, get, request, http-status-code-404

I have an application which allows users to create wishes. I use the title of each wish to make an api request to unsplash to download a picture. I now have the problem, that a user can enter a title which doesnt return any images from unsplash. In this case I'd like to use a placeholder image but my code stops after getting an 404 error. Is there a way to ignore this error and just continue my loop?

```
 public function fetchImagesFromUnsplash() {

    $wishes = $this->repository->findAll();
    foreach ($wishes as $wish) {
            try {
                $response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', 'https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random', [
                    'query' => [
                        'query' => $wish->getDescription(),
                        'client_id' => 'oa1DsGebE8ehCV9SrvcA1mCx-2QfvnufUKgsIY5N0Mk'
                    ]
                ]);

            } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
            }

            if ($response) {
                $data = $response->getContent();
                $data = json_decode($data, true);
                $imageLink = $data['urls']['raw'];
                $rawImage = file_get_contents($imageLink);

                if ($rawImage) {
                    file_put_contents("public/images/" . sprintf('imageWish%d.jpg', $wish->getId()), $rawImage);
                    $wish->setImagePath(sprintf('public/images/imageWish%d.jpg', $wish->getId()));
                } else {
                $wish->setImagePath('placeholder.png');
                }
                $this->em->flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
  public function fetchImagesFromUnsplash() {

    $wishes = $this->repository->findAll();
    foreach ($wishes as $wish) {
            try {
                $response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', 'https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random', [
                    'query' => [
                        'query' => $wish->getDescription(),
                        'client_id' => 'oa1DsGebE8ehCV9SrvcA1mCx-2QfvnufUKgsIY5N0Mk'
                    ]
                ]);

            } catch (NotFoundHttpException $e) {
            }

            if ($response) {
                $data = $response->getContent();
                $data = json_decode($data, true);
                $imageLink = $data['urls']['raw'];
                $rawImage = file_get_contents($imageLink);

                if ($rawImage) {
                    file_put_contents("public/images/" . sprintf('imageWish%d.jpg', $wish->getId()), $rawImage);
                    $wish->setImagePath(sprintf('public/images/imageWish%d.jpg', $wish->getId()));
                } else {
                    $wish->setImagePath('placeholder.png');
                }

            }  
        }
    $this->em->flush();

}
```

but it still stops after the first 404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_client.html#handling-exceptions):

> When the HTTP status code of the response is in the 300-599 range
>   (i.e. 3xx, 4xx or 5xx) your code is expected to handle it. If you
>   don't do that, the getHeaders() and getContent() methods throw an
>   appropriate exception

You have to check the `$response->getStatusCode()`, or prepare to handle a `ClientException` (representing 4xx status codes).

Comment: You were right, I used this though:    $data = $response->getContent(false); this ignores the error and instead just gives me the original response, thank you!

Comment: @Rugo you should consider checking the status code still, you would handle a 500 or a 401 differently, right?

Comment: You're right, I'll check the status code then, didn't think that far. Thanks again!